# Fix malformed line error

Tags: 12.04

[see up right. I have an error called malformed line 59 in source list.
The list of sources could not be read. How can i solve it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a55l3.png)

Comment: How about this: Open a Terminal then run this command: `sudo more /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `vi` or `vim` editor

- go with `$> vi [yourfilename]`
- end then press *Insert* from your keyboard
- remove the mulfunctioned line
- lastly, press *ESC* and type `:`+`wq` and press *Enter*